# Split the string. get first value of split SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have a table called `TableReason` with a column called `Reason`.

`Reason` datatype is `varchar(100)` and contains values like this `2,-2,22,33,0,2` for one row

I need to write an update statement for this table to accomplish: only need first value of split with comma, ie. 2 only needed.

```
 update TableReason
 set reason=--please help me on this.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
...
set reason=CASE CHARINDEX(',', reason)
                         WHEN 0 THEN reason
                         WHEN 1 THEN ''
                         ELSE LEFT(reason, CHARINDEX(',', reason)-1)
           END
```

This deals with the 3 cases of

- no comma
- first character is a comma
- a number followed by a comma