# Validate the first part of a splitted string

Tags: sql-server

I need to validate in my query  if the value of a string (the first part) is equal to a definited value, for instance:

```
String
----------
F11-EDEDED
F1-SAFSDA
F455-ADADD
F11-ASDA-FAFA
```

And validate when the string is F11, i was searching something like split on vba, but i can't find it.

Im working with :

Case when ("splitted string") =F11 then X)

Comment: answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15019037/split-the-string-get-first-value-of-split-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Left()` and `Charindex()` to grab the beginning of your strings.

```
Declare @str varchar(100)='F11-ASDA-FAFA'

Select @str,Case When left(@str,charindex('-',@str)-1)='F11' Then 1 Else 0 End
```